# What is the difference between Translate and Top in CSS

Tags: css, translate-animation

What is the difference between `translate` and `top` in CSS ?

Example :

What is the difference between

this : http://jsfiddle.net/QS4Ha/

```css
@keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% { top: 90px; }
    40% { top: 60px; }
    60% { top: 80px; }
    
    }@-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% { top: 90px; }
    40% { top: 60px; }
    60% { top: 80px; }
    
    }@-moz-keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% { top: 90px; }
    40% { top: 60px; }
    60% { top: 80px; }
    
    }@-o-keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% { top: 90px; }
    40% { top: 60px; }
    60% { top: 80px; }
}

#bounceElement{
    position: relative;
    width : 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #DF3A01;
    animation: bounce 0.7s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="bounceElement">
    
</div>
```

and this : http://jsfiddle.net/GWYPb/

```css
@keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(90px); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translateY(60px); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translateY(80px); }
    
    }@-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(90px); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translateY(60px); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translateY(80px); }
    
    }@-moz-keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(90px); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translateY(60px); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translateY(80px); }
    
    }@-o-keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(90px); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translateY(60px); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translateY(80px); }
}

#bounceElement{
    position: relative;
    width : 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #DF3A01;
    animation: bounce 0.7s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="bounceElement">
    
</div>
```

Which is better to use ?

Comment: the top css-property exists for a long time. translate is new. it is part of css 3. In you example both of them have the same effect. with translate you are also able to translate the div on the x axis at once. to get more information about the two properties please ask google...

Comment: The properties are defined in CSS specifications. You could rather ask what they have in common (not much) rather than ask about differences. And asking which is better is vague and primarily an opinion poll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [html5 Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) which strongly advises animating with translate.

Why? Changing the 'top' property triggers layout, translate doesn't.

> You should always look to avoid animating properties that will trigger
>   layout or paints, both of which are expensive and may lead to skipped
>   frames. Declarative animations are preferable to imperative since the
>   browser has the opportunity to optimize ahead of time.

Also see [this post](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/):

> The top/left has very large time to paint each frame, which results in
>   a choppier transition. All the CSS including some big box shadows, are
>   computed on the CPU and composited against that gradient backdrop
>   every frame. The translate version, on the other hand, gets the laptop
>   element elevated onto it’s own layer on the GPU (called a
>   RenderLayer). Now that it sits on its own layer, any 2D transform, 3D
>   transform, or opacity changes can happen purely on the GPU which will
>   stay extremely fast and still get us quick frame rates.