# What is the difference between moving my element using transform and position properties in CSS?

Tags: css

More specifically what is the difference between

```css
transform: translateY(100px);
```

and

```css
position: relative;
top: 100px;
```

? AS much as I know they both move my element downward by 100 pixels.

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180735/what-is-the-difference-between-translate-and-top-in-css

Comment: Note that while the post @maxkroon links, and the article which links from that are well worth reading, be careful of its relevance. The article compares the performance of `translate` with `top` used with `position:absolute`. `position:relative` is a very different beast to `position:absolute` and possibly even more so today than a decade ago when that article was written. So, if performance is a concern. I advise you check for yourself with your use case, rather than accept it at face value.

Comment: read about [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and  [layout paint composite](https://web.dev/rendering-performance/)

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/details/Dobxgm

Comment: See link above for examples of each.

Answer (score 0):

Very little. But `position:relative` can be used with `display:inline` elements.

```css
span.one {
  transform: translateY(100px);
} 

span.two {
  position: relative; top: 100px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 50px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height:130px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="one">test one</span>
</div>  
<div>
  <span class="two">test two</span>
</div>
```

Comment: there is also the case when percentage is involved

Comment: And stacking context considerations can make quite a difference.